# Compress image using JPEG Lossless and convert the image to Base64Encoded String

Tags: java, image, lossless-compression

We have a requirement to compress an image which will be of size around 50 KB - 75 KB within 25KB limit. We were following the example given in http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/. by specifying the quality as 0.1f we are able to reduce the size of the image below 25 KB. But the image looses its quality.

We need your suggestion on:

1. How we can compress the image to be within 25 KB without any loss on the quality?
2. After compressing we are converting the image byte array to Base64Encoded String. After this the string content is exceeding the size limitation of 25KB. How can i control this size as well?

We need your help in resolving this. Please help.

Comment: Your requirements sound somewhat unrealistic. Compression at that magnitude (between 50%-66%) is bound to be lossy in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG does not support lossless compression. Your best bet will be to use the new [Google WebP format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/). It compresses pretty good and is lossless. There is no point in converting it to Base64. That is  a ridiculous operation when you are trying to keep the data as small as possible.